# atmospheric correction with PCI

Tags: atmospheric-correction, geomatica

I'm not very experienced in this.

I am atmospherically correcting Landsat 8 images with ATCOR module in PCI Geomatica. I see that my final output reflectance values are not between 0.1 to 1.0, indicative of reflectance values. Also I read PCI manual and realized atmospherically corrected images are in percentage. I feel my reflectance values should range between 0.1 and 1.0. Any idea on this please (or can I just divide my image by 100 - i.e. converting percentage to decimal)?

Comment: What values do you have? Some software (i.e. The ARCSI atmospheric correction software) scales the values by 1000 so the image can be stored as an integer16 and not a float 32, in order to reduce the file size

Comment: Values range between 0.1 and 5 for WorldView-2, and 5.0 and 18.0 for Landsat 8